# Playing video from internet

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I am a new C# developer. I a trying to fetch mp3 music from online sources and play the music in my windows store app that I am developing. I am using the MediaElement to play videos or songs, but I need to know if i can set the source of the MediaLement to a URL in order to play the required song. I am using the Visual studio professional 2013. Thanks for all kind of helping.

Comment: Yes you can, that's a built-in function.

Comment: Could you please help me out with this method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <MediaElement Source="http://www.gravomaster.com/alarm/sounds/Car_Alarm_Device_With_Horn_-_Ringtone.mp3" AutoPlay="true" />
```

Comment: Thank you Bidy, I wasn't expected to be that easy :)